How to implement localization using @azure/communication-react?
I want to implement localization using @azure/communication-react with following usecase:

It should take OS language by default
User can manually change the language

I went through the documentation. However, we have not used their ControlBar component. We are having customized control bar with MicrophoneButton, EndCallButton.
How can I apply azure localization to customized web calling application?

Could you please clarify what you mean by 'localize' in the context of the 'Web Calling' application? It would be helpful if you could provide specific details, as I'm not entirely sure what localization entails in this scenario.

I want to implement multi-lingula functionality in using azure communication services. We are developing one app similar to Microsoft teams
